# Air200 GSM module have problem with AT commands, Why?

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command

I bought an air200 gsm module and this module won't work properly. in one hand i use the standard at command for sending Unicode SMS, but cant sends Unicode. from the other hand when I send text SMS, for every SMS I send the network less my credit double cost. anybody can please help to solve the problem?

---

1. I send the following command for sending SMS:

   AT+CMGF=1

   AT+CSMP=17,11,0,0

   AT+CSCS="GSM"

   AT+CMGS="number come here"

   SMS body

   // Ctrl+Z to send SMS

in this case, I can send SMS message but however, I send just one SMS it decreases my credit double time.

---

2. I use the following command to send Unicode SMS but it gets the error:

   AT+CMGF=0

   AT+CSCS="UCS2"

   AT+CSMP=49,167,0,8

   AT+CMGS="number come here"

   d8b3d984d8a7d985

   // Ctrl+Z to send SMS

everything goes OK until I send AT+CMGS="number" and it response ERROR.
anybody please can get an idea? whats happen exactly? 
I send at command under raspbian Linux on the raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

> AT+CMGS="number come here"

I suspect that you have not UCS2 encoded the phone number. Notice that after you run `AT+CSCS="UCS2"` *every single string* must be encoded that way, so for instance to switch from UCS2 to UTF-8 would be `AT+CSCS="005500540046002D0038"`.